# Check box click issue in iOS 7 and above

Tags: jquery, ios, events, touch

We have implemented a web page with multiple checkboxes (more than 40). There are multiple(more than 170) event handlers(click, mouseover, mouseout, change, changeDate, focus, keyup, keypress, mousedown, touchcancel, touchend, touchstart) in the same web page which is delegated to the body i.e starts like $('body').on() instead of closest static parent. In this page when a checkbox is checked multiple times (even twice sometimes) the browser becomes unresponsive only in iOS 7 and above. Even after changing the event delegation to closest static parent, the problem still persist.

Can someone please help on this regard, or suggest some reading for this!

Comment: Without seeing any code it's really hard to say what is wrong with the code. Seems you are binding events in some other events. Post some code...

Comment: what happens to them they all trigger at the same time ?\

Comment: No, they all don't trigger at once. But most of the events delegated to body and which will be triggered only when it is required. For example :  $('body').on('click', '.checklist[type="checkbox"]', function() {});